# ejs-chiplist selected value pass in OnChage Event

Tags: javascript, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am using **syncfusion** for displaying the list of subjects.

```
<ejs-chiplist id="chip-SubjectTags" selection="Single" click="FilterSubject" cssClass="e-primary">
<e-chips>
@foreach (var mySubject in (List<FilterSubjectInfo>)ViewBag.FilterTags)
{
<e-chip text="@mySubject.Name" value="@mySubject.SubjectTagID" enabled="true"></e-chip>
}
</e-chips>
</ejs-chiplist>
```

When selecting the subject let's say MATHS OR SCIENCE it calls the **function FilterSubject(e)** and fetch the data.

Now I have one dropdown list in which I have a list of **Teacher's** names.

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTeacher" onchange="getTeacherVideo(this)">
</select>
```

```
function getTeacherVideo(selectObject) {
var value = selectObject.value;
//var abcValue = document.getElementById('chip-SubjectTags').selectObject;
//console.log(abcValue);
console.log(value);
}
```

Here in **getTeacherVideo()** function I want to use the **chip-SubjectTags**, selected chip value.

How can I access **chip-SubjectTags** chip value in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using the getSelectedChips method of Chip component as demonstrated in the below code snippet,

```
<ejs-chiplist id="chip-avatar" click="FilterSubject" selection="Single" enableDelete="true">
<e-chips>
    . . .
</e-chips>
```

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" onchange="getTeacherVideo(this)">
<script>
function getTeacherVideo(selectObject) {
    var chip = document.getElementsByClassName('e-chip-list')[0].ej2_instances[0];//Chip instance.
    var selected = chip.getSelectedChips(); //to get the value of the selected chip
    console.log(selected);
}
```

API Reference: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/api/chips/chipList/#getselectedchips